# How to store only the first occurrence in a for loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements, find-occurrences

I tried to code `k` as a cumulatively increasing variable until it reaches `15`. `j` is supposed to store the point when `k` exceeds `10` for the first time. However, obviously, `j` is going to store all the occurrences instead which is not desirable for my purpose.

```
set.seed(324)
j.ind <- 1
j <- numeric()
k <- numeric()
init.k <- 0
for (i in 1:50){
  k[i] <- init.k + abs(rnorm(1,0,1))
  init.k <- k[i]
  if (k[i] >= 10){
    j[j.ind] <- i
    j.ind <- j.ind + 1
  }
  init.k <- ifelse(init.k >= 15, 0, init.k)
}
```

Can you suggest a way to do this which will not slow down the loop significantly as the original problem is rather huge? For this example with the given seed, `j` is supposed to be `17` and `36`

Comment: You want to save the indices where your cummulative sum of generated values exceeds 10 and then, reset your cummulative vector and save the indices where the cummulative value exceeds 15. Isn`t it?

Comment: Yes, I am adding my own solution but I feel like it can be done more elegantly.

Comment: Ok, I edited my previous answer.

Comment: @Rel_Ai Please check `Rcpp` version I've added to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72934707/6574038).

Comment: @jay.sf Thank you for your solution. I will check and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Reduce` with option `accumulate=TRUE`, in combination with `rle`:

```r
set.seed(324)
k.vectorized <- abs(rnorm(50,0,1))

# cumsum with reinit for k>=15
k.cumsum <- Reduce(f=function(x,y) {ifelse(x+y>=15,0,x+y)} ,x=k.vectorized,init=0,accumulate = T)

# extract intervals above 10
r <- rle(k.cumsum>=10)

# output result
cumsum(r$length)[which(r$values)-1]
#> [1] 17 36
```

Comment: I am getting this when I am running your solution: "Numeric: lengths (0, 13) differ"

Comment: See my edit, seems to be working fine on example data

Comment: This is rather elegant but I was wondering about the speed. It seems your solution is a bit slower than the solution I provided in the answer whereas I was expecting yours to be much faster as you didn't use a loop.

Comment: Loops aren't always wrong ;-). If you need more speed, it would be easy to implement the same loops in `Rcpp`. This is what I would do if there's no speed gain in a vectorized solution, because loops are in this case easier to understand.

Comment: Done, `Rcpp` added to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72934707/6574038)!

Answer (score 2):

Check `k` of previous iteration, of course only if it exists, i.e. `length > 1`. Watch out better if integer or double.

```
set.seed(324)
j.ind <- 1L
j <- integer()
k <- numeric()
init.k <- 0

for (i in 1:50) {
  k[i] <- init.k + abs(rnorm(1, 0, 1))
  init.k <- k[i]
  if (k[i] >= 10 && length(k) > 1L && !k[i - 1L] >= 10) {
    j[j.ind] <- i
    j.ind <- j.ind + 1L
  }
  if (init.k >= 15) {
    init.k <- 0
  }
}

j
# [1] 17 36
```

You could also check this `repeat` loop, I've implemented your `flag` idea.

```
set.seed(324)
k <- 0
i <- 1L
j <- integer()
flag <- FALSE
max.it <- 50L

repeat {
  k <- k + abs(rnorm(1, 0, 1))
  if (k >= 10 && !flag) {
    j <- c(j, i)
    flag <- TRUE
  } 
  if (k < 10) {
    flag <- FALSE
  }
  i <- i + 1L
  if (k >= 15) k <- 0
  if (i >= max.it) break
}

j
# [1] 17 36
```

As suggested by [*@Waldi*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72934116/how-to-store-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-for-loop/72934707#comment128827030_72934579), here comes a lightning fast `Rcpp` version.

```
rcppfun <- '
std::vector<int> f(int mxit) {
  double k = 0;
  int i = 0;
  std::vector<int> j;
  bool flag = false;
  while (i < mxit) {
    k = k + std::abs(R::rnorm(0, 1));
    if (k >= 10 && !flag) {
      j.push_back(i + 1);
      flag = true;
    }
    if (k < 10) {
      flag = false;
    }
    i = i + 1;
    if (k >= 15) {
      k = 0;
    }
  }
  return j;
}
'
library(Rcpp)
rcpp_loop <- cppFunction(rcppfun)
```

### Benchmark

According to the benchmark with max.it=1e4 it turns out that the `repeat` loop is fast<strike>est</strike>, but of course the `Rcpp` version is even faster.

```
Unit: microseconds
                expr      min        lq       mean     median       uq       max neval cld
     op_loop(max_it) 38109.40 38737.472 41511.3945 42528.4975 43952.55 44049.257    10  bc
    for_loop(max_it) 38298.01 42801.249 44998.1564 43184.6190 50846.51 53938.702    10   c
 repeat_loop(max_it) 33013.92 33713.646 37748.3945 38699.6135 39574.62 45676.726    10  b 
  cumsum_rle(max_it) 41720.00 41921.924 42569.8268 42192.0410 42536.18 45228.849    10   c
   rcpp_loop(max_it)   739.16   740.167   743.8714   741.3965   745.60   753.774    10 a
```

---

*Code:*

```
op_loop <- \(max.it=max_it) {
  set.seed(324)
  j.ind <- 1
  j <- numeric()
  k <- numeric()
  init.k <- 0
  j.flag <- FALSE
  for (i in 1:max.it){
    k[i] <- init.k + abs(rnorm(1,0,1))
    init.k <- k[i]
    if (k[i] >= 10 && j.flag == FALSE){
      j[j.ind] <- i
      j.ind <- j.ind + 1
      j.flag <- TRUE
    }
    if (k[i] >= 15){
      init.k <- 0
      j.flag <- FALSE
    }
  }
  j
}

for_loop <- \(max.it=max_it) {
  set.seed(324)
  j.ind <- 1L
  j <- integer()
  k <- numeric()
  init.k <- 0
  for (i in 1:max.it) {
    k[i] <- init.k + abs(rnorm(1, 0, 1))
    init.k <- k[i]
    if (k[i] >= 10 && length(k) > 1L && !k[i - 1L] >= 10) {
      j[j.ind] <- i
      j.ind <- j.ind + 1L
    }
    if (init.k >= 15) {
      init.k <- 0
    }
  }
  j
}

repeat_loop <- \(max.it=max_it) {
  set.seed(324); k <- 0; i <- 1L; j <- numeric(); flag <- FALSE
  repeat {
    k <- k + abs(rnorm(1, 0, 1))
    if (k >= 10 && !flag) {
      j <- c(j, i)
      flag <- TRUE
    } 
    if (k < 10) {
      flag <- FALSE
    }
    i <- i + 1L
    if (k >= 15) k <- 0
    if (i >= max.it) break
  }
  j
}

cumsum_rle <- \(max.it=max_it) {
  set.seed(324)
  k.vectorized <- abs(rnorm(max.it,0,1))
  k.cumsum <- Reduce(f=function(x,y) {ifelse(x+y>=15,0,x+y)} ,x=k.vectorized,init=0,accumulate = T)
  r <- rle(k.cumsum>=10)
  cumsum(r$length)[which(r$values)-1]
}

stopifnot(all.equal(op_loop(100), for_loop(100)) &
            all.equal(op_loop(100), repeat_loop(100)) &
            all.equal(op_loop(100), cumsum_rle(100)) &
            all.equal(op_loop(100), {set.seed(324);rcpp_loop(100)})
)
    
max_it <- 1e4
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  op_loop(max_it), for_loop(max_it), repeat_loop(max_it), cumsum_rle(max_it), rcpp_loop(max_it), times=10L
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have how I would do the search

```
# Set seed
  set.seed(324)
# Number of simulated values
  n <- 50
# Specific values (cummulative sum)
  v1 <- 10;  v2 <- 15
  
# Generate all the values for k
  k <- abs(rnorm(n,0,1))
# Cummulative sum of k vector's values
  k.cum <- cumsum(k)
  
# How many indices are we looking for? [Excluding the first one]
  n.times <- floor((k.cum[n]-v1)/v2)
# Values to look for at k.cum
  v <- c(v1,v1 +v2*(1:n.times))
# Vector to save the indices
  ind <- vector()
# Indices
  for (i in 1:length(v)){
    ind[i] <-min(which(k.cum>=v[i])) 
  }
```

Comment: its missing the point that after k > 15 it will restart

Answer (score 0):

This is my own solution but I am expecting a better one.

```
set.seed(324)
j.ind <- 1
j <- numeric()
k <- numeric()
init.k <- 0
j.flag <- FALSE
for (i in 1:50){
  k[i] <- init.k + abs(rnorm(1,0,1))
  init.k <- k[i]
  if (k[i] >= 10 && j.flag == FALSE){
    j[j.ind] <- i
    j.ind <- j.ind + 1
    j.flag <- TRUE
  }
  if (k[i] >= 15){
    init.k <- 0
    j.flag <- FALSE
  }
}
```